# Write function to a new file Python 3

Tags: python, function, file-writing

how can I write a function in a new file in Python IE:

```
def fun_one(x):
    print(x)
file_handler = open('file.py','a')
file_handler.write(fun_one)
file_handler.close()
quit()
```

Comment: I would question *why* you're generating Python code files on the fly in the first place…!?

Comment: Hi deceze,thanks for prompt reply, I'm doing so as this will be inserted in a for loop that will generate function that will open different websocket for different items of the for loop.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ Though I know very little about what you're trying to do there, that sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inspect`:

```
import inspect


def fun_one(x):
    print(x)

with open('file.py', 'a') as f:
    f.write(inspect.getsource(fun_one))
```

Your *file.py* will contain:

```
def fun_one(x):
    print(x)
```

Also, note that you don't need `quit()` and that you can open and close the file using `with`.

That being said, I remain curious about why you would need such thing.